# Waiting for build to finish in preview window

Tags: android

i use android studio 3.3.2 
when i make the project then went to layout section and open the preview window
it's still loading

**`"Waiting for build to finish..."`**

please help me

Preview windows still loading (issue Image)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved it by choosing *Sync Project with Gradle* Files.You can find it using Find Action shortcut Ctrl+Shift+A .

Comment: i also have face this problem.i think this could solve this problem.

Comment: Wait for the build process to finish and then rebuild your project once. Also try to sync with gradle